# How to make two user friends in ejabberd using ejabberdctl command?

Tags: php, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I have installed ejabberd in one my server, let the server ip be = 0.0.0.001 and registerd two users using below command

```
ejabberdctl register kumar 0.0.0.001 kumar
ejabberdctl register rani 0.0.0.001 rani
```

Syntax for registering user is:

```
ejabberdctl register username host password
```

Now what i need is i want to make these users as friends by using ejabberdctl ..!!

What i tried :

```
ejabberdctl add_rosteritem kandan 0.0.0.001 rani
```

Note: I am using mysql as default database.

Could someone help me out and let me know the syntax for addrosteritem please..!!! Thanks in advance..!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax to add roster item:

```
Command Name: add_rosteritem

  Arguments: localuser::binary
             localserver::binary
             user::binary
             server::binary
             nick::binary
             group::binary
             subs::binary
```

Hence, the command should be

```
ejabberdctl add_rosteritem kandan hostname rani hostname none none both
```

Comment: i configured Ejabberd on  Amazon and using username and pasword i am able to view ejabber admin panel where access rules are showing , could you please help me where i need to change to make(connect) it work for amazon ejabberd server  not localhost . My ios app is working perfectly on localhost ( ios app with adium and ejabberd working perfectly)

Comment: If ejabberd is configured & running properly & port 5222 is open. Then you should be able to connect it with <server-ip>:5222 port with default configuration.

Comment: in ios code where should i need to add <serverid> , when i hit <server-ip>:5280/admin on url then it shows Ejabberd web panel which includes access rules , online user , register etc . I have configured my ios to connect with localhost (having ejbaberd) so how do i connect to remote ejabberd server thats my question .

Comment: you need to hit <server-ip>:5222 to connect with ur ejabberd server. You should have a look into https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework